# TableView error after animating in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In my app I am having a view controller with a button on top of it. When the button is clicked a table view will animate from the left to right.below image display the content of the screen when the button is not pressed.
The right side image displays the table view when the button is pressed.

[image: image before the button pressed]
[image]

This code runs when the button is pressed.

```
-(void) profileButtonClicked
{
profileTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-220, 0, 220, height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
profileTable.delegate=self;
profileTable.dataSource=self;
profileTable.backgroundColor=[HexColorCode colorWithHexastring:@"252020"];
profileTable.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubView: profileTable];
if (profileButton.tag==1)
{

    CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake( 220.0f + self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    self.view.center = newLeftCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    CGPoint newLeftCenterForTable = CGPointMake( 1- profileTable.frame.size.width / 2.0f, profileTable.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    profileTable.center = newLeftCenterForTable;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    profileTable.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     [self.view addSubview:profileTable];
    profileButton.tag=2;

}
else
{
    profileButton.tag=1;

    CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake(  self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    self.view.center = newLeftCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    CGPoint newLeftCenterForTable = CGPointMake(  profileTable.frame.size.width / 2.0f-220, profileTable.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    profileTable.center = newLeftCenterForTable;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
}
```

My problem is that, when a press a row on the table, it is not recognized. That is. it is not entering the

> didSelectrowAtIndexPath:

Comment: The delegate of UITableView has been added?

Comment: ya, i have added, i tried using break points, when i click on a row, it is not entering the delegate method

Comment: That's probably because your tableview is outside the controller's view frame. What are you trying to do by setting it outside ?

Comment: in the first image, it will be outside, then, after animation see the second image, it comes inside

Comment: Yes but you also move your controller's view so it is still outside.

Comment: then, can u get me some suggestion for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your tableview is outside your controller's view frame. What you should keep in mind is that `self.view` should not move. (i've never seen a case where it was useful).

What i would recommend is having a parent view controller. You will add the tableview to your parent and it will be the delegate. You will then add a child view controller which is your current controller (the one displaying Taxi Match).

In your parent view controller :

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
    yourController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
    [self addChilViewController:yourController];
    [self.view addSubview:yourController.view];

    profileTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-220, 0, 220, height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    profileTable.delegate=self;
    profileTable.dataSource=self;
    profileTable.backgroundColor=[HexColorCode colorWithHexastring:@"252020"];
    profileTable.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.view addSubView: profileTable];
    ....
}
```

Then when you touch your button in your child view controller you should call the parent and do :

```
-(void)moveController{
    CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake( 220.0f + self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    yourController.view.center = newLeftCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    CGPoint newLeftCenterForTable = CGPointMake( 1- profileTable.frame.size.width / 2.0f, profileTable.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    profileTable.center = newLeftCenterForTable;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    profileTable.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     [self.view addSubview:profileTable];
    profileButton.tag=2;
}
```

Comment: i got u, thanks a lot, I got ur explanation. I edited in my code, thank u

Answer (score -1):

Please check the delegate method, I think you would have used didDeselectRow inplace of didSelectRow. Also make sure that you have connected the delegate.

Comment: i have done all this, if i dont use animation and if i add the table view in the view, giving origin (0,0), the delegate method works

Comment: Okay, then try to bring table view in fron of the view controller by using bringSubViewToFront property..